# What does $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}}$ evaluate to?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Problem:

> Suppose that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable within a
> neighborhood of the point $a$ and $f''(a) = 4$. Compute \begin{align*}
>  \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}} \end{align*}

I have done this work
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^{2}} &= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - f'(a)}{x-a} \\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(a)-f'(a)}{x-a} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
This makes sense, but I am not confident in my answer because I didn't use the given that $f''(a) = 4$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a simple example, e.g. $f(x) = 2x^2$ at $a=0$. Then evaluate all those expressions, and you'll detect where the error is.

Comment: not zero. Write out the Taylor series with remainder up to the $(x-a)^2$ term

Answer (score 3):

According to Taylor's theorem, if $f$ is twice differentiable in $a$ (most versions require continuous differentiability, but it isn't actually necessary), then there exists a remainder function $r(x)$ with
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{r(x)}{(x-a)^2}=0$$
such that
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2+r(x).$$
With a little bit of algebra we get that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^2}=\frac{r(x)}{(x-a)^2}+\frac{1}{2}f''(a).$$
The limit now evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}f''(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not $0$ in general. Your fallacy was in [neglecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Indeterminate_form_0/0) the fact that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^\prime(a)\in O(x-a)$. By L'Hôpital's rule, the limit is$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^\prime(x)-f^\prime(a)}{2(x-a)}=\tfrac12f^{\prime\prime}(a).$$